# c++ constexpr and reference

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

Because of C++14 does not have constexpr array, I tried to create my own.
Here is the full code :

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class constexpr_array {
public:
    constexpr constexpr_array() = default;

    template<typename U>
    constexpr constexpr_array(std::initializer_list<U> values) :
        m_array{} {
        const U *it = values.begin();
        for(std::size_t i{0}; i < N; ++i) {
            m_array[i] = *it++;
        }
    }

    constexpr constexpr_array(const constexpr_array&) = default;
    constexpr constexpr_array(constexpr_array&&) = default;

    constexpr T& operator[](std::size_t index) {
        return m_array[index];
    }

    constexpr const T& operator[](std::size_t index) const {
        return m_array[index];
    }

    constexpr const constexpr_array *operator&() const {
        return this;
    }

private:
    T m_array[N];
};
```

It works well, however I wonder why it is not allowed, (maybe only by MSVC?) to have a initializer_list constructor like that :

```
template<typename U>
constexpr constexpr_array(std::initializer_list<U> values) :
    m_array{} {
    const U *it = values.begin();
    for(auto &v : m_array) {
        v = *it++;
    }
}
```

I got c2131-expression-did-not-evaluate-to-a-constant in Visual Studio 2017. The error is at line `for(auto &v : m_array)`.

Here is a sample to try :

```
template<std::size_t N, const constexpr_array<std::size_t, N> *indices>
struct array_to_index_sequence {
    template<typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
    struct as_index_sequence{};

    template<std::size_t ...Is>
    struct as_index_sequence<std::index_sequence<Is...>> : std::index_sequence<(*indices)[Is]...>{};
};
template<int... I>
struct a {
    static constexpr constexpr_array<std::size_t, 3> compute() {
        return {I...};
    }
    static constexpr constexpr_array<std::size_t, 3> t = compute();
    using i = typename array_to_index_sequence<3, &t>::template as_index_sequence<>;
};

#include <string>

template<std::size_t ...I>
void f(std::tuple<int, std::string, double, double> t, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
     int a[] = {0, (std::cout << std::get<I>(t) << std::endl, 0)...};
}

int main()
{
    f(std::make_tuple(5, "lolll", 1.0, 2.0), typename a<2, 1, 0>::i{});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What version of MSVS are you using and what is the compiler error?

Comment: FWIW g++ and clang++ have no issue with this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0c55dc11802b8fe

Comment: So okay, I usual with such a question, it is a bug from MSVC... MSVC does not like constexpr at all

Comment: Compiles for me on VS2017 15.5.7, maybe you need to update.

Comment: I am using 15.6.2. I am using C++14 and not c++latest. I edited my post for one example.

Comment: Because you'r constructor is not constexpr, and it's contains loop - so it can not be constexpr yet. And check [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: @VictorGubin My constructor is constexpr. the std::array constructor is not constexpr before c++17.

Comment: `std::array`'s constructor uses aggregate initialization, so it should be `constexpr`. It is the other methods which are not `constexpr` (as `operator[]`) until C++17.